# How to find where a connection get closed

Tags: tcp, connection, apache2

I'll start with that we have a server hosting a big file (8Mb) behind a reverse proxy in apache2.

When I try to download that file locally using wget or curl, the connection get closed. The client doesn't say anything at all.. except that the connection got closed.

```
  0 8619k    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0{ [8000 bytes data]
 86 8619k   86 7464k    0     0  80723      0  0:01:49  0:01:34  0:00:15 66791* transfer closed with 1110002 bytes remaining to read
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
 87 8619k   87 7536k    0     0  80763      0  0:01:49  0:01:35  0:00:14 62315
* Closing connection 0
curl: (18) transfer closed with 1110002 bytes remaining to read
```

It's with curl with `-v` but it doesn't say that the server closed the connection and or if the connection got lost.

I tried to increase the timeout and worker alive time on the server behind the proxy and apache2. But nothing changes... I tried to host the file statically with apache2 without the reverse proxy but then again the connection get closed.

One last information is, I'm located on the other side of the earth where the server is located. I can expect some lag and lower speed but is there a way to find out if the connection is closed on our ends or somewhere inbetween?

My partner which is located closer to the server doesn't have that problem and his speed is in the range of 2Mb/s while I have only 80Kb/s considering that I have a 20mbit connection it's pretty slow.

Comment: One (weird) reasson for that happening is TCP packets dying due to their TTL been too low. Anyways, you better get a [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) running and see what's going on.

Comment: @Alex if that was the case, how would I know? By the way, I can ssh to the server without problem (thought ssh might be good enough to reconnect without me noticing).